# Cookie not getting generated on "Production Server"

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I am using ngx-cookie. On login, I am setting the cookie like:

```
this.cookieService.put('cookie_name', JSON.stringify(user), { domain:localhost' });
```

On logout I am deleting the cookie like:

```
this.cookieService.remove('cookie_name', { domain: 'localhost' });
```

Unable to generate the cookie on the production server (application tab will show the list of cookie if any cookie gets created). So any idea what I have to use to fix this issue on the production server. The same code is working fine in the local server.

Comment: is cookie logic working fine on development server?

Comment: Thank you for your response..we figured it out..by the way cookie logic is working fine except few cases(cookie is not getting removed on logout in few of the cases).